# Transform a Dictionary to List

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary

How can I transform this dictionary to list

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

dict.Add("1", new List<string>() { "a", "b" });
dict.Add("2", new List<string>() { "a", "c" });
```

I'm expecting this output

```
List<dynamic> = new List<dynamic>() 
{
    new { id = "1", value = "a" }
    new { id = "1", value = "a" }
    new { id = "2", value = "a" }
    new { id = "2", value = "a" }
}
```

I've tried this but can't get the values of the nested collections:

```
dict.Select(c => new { id=c.Key, value= c.Value })
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? and I guess the values of `id` and `value` should be different..

Comment: im stuck into this `dict.Select(c => new { id=c.Key, value= c.Value })`

Comment: For next time please show your effort from the start. Will save you some downvotes.. without that how can we tell you actually tried anything and it isn't just another "do my coding for me" question..

Comment: What do you mean by "can't get the values of the nested collections"? Your `value` property will be of type `List<string>`. Please provide a [mcve] to clarify your question.

Answer (score 7):

Use `SelectMany` to return multiple items for each `KeyValuePair`. Then for each `pair` use `Select` on the `Value`:

```
var result = dict.SelectMany(pair => pair.Value.Select(item => 
    new { id = pair.Key, value = item }));
```

Result:

[image]